# Direct Sum of a Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm stuck on the below question and was wondering if someone could maybe give me a hint? My idea is to show that $\operatorname{span}(\bigcup E_n)$ is dense in $D$, but if I'm completely honest I have no idea where to begin.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $D \subset H$ be such that the linear space spanned
by $D$ is dense in $H$. Let $(E_n)_n$ be a sequence of mutually orthogonal closed linear
subspaces of $H$. Prove that if\
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|P_{E_n}u\|^2 =\|u\|^2 \quad \forall u \in D$$
then $H = \bigoplus^{\infty}_{n=1}E_n$.

Many Thanks

Comment: If $A:=span(\bigcup E_n)$ was not dense, then $A^\perp\neq \{0\}$. Pick $0\neq v\in A^\perp.$ However, then $P_{E_n} v =0$ for all $n$, which gives you a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much! The hint was excellent!

Comment: I suggest that you write a complete answer, then future people have all the details and the community can give you feedback on the proof (whether details are missing ect).